# Django ListView inserting blank <li> after each element

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and trying to grasp why or how to mitigate the extra `<li>` and have not found anything yet. Here is an image of what the output is doing.
**EDIT:** I have tried cleaning the string as suggested below and still no luck. This happens even when I ran through the Django Tutorial. I know I can use JS or JQuery to remove them, however being as basic as this is, and knowing there are ONLY 2 objects for the model, I would like to know why it inserts this additional

[image: li elements]

And here is a snippet of my template:

```
{% extends "base_templates/stations.html" %}

{% block station_content %}
    <h2>Stations</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for station in object_list %}
            {% if station.name.strip != "" %}
            <li>{{ station.name }}<li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT:** Here is my view for this template as well

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Customer, CustomerContact, Station, SubcontractorContact

# Create your views here.

class CustomerView(ListView):
    model = Customer

class StationView(ListView):
    model = Station
```

Comment: If you just check it for being empty, it might not validate for white space. Trim the string before you check it for being empty.

Comment: " " and ""  are not equal.

Comment: Don't screenshot text. That code block, is text. Copy and paste it in the question and add code formatting.

Comment: I apologize, I tried to get the code in but the editor wouldnt format it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, THANK YOU so much everyone who contributed... HOWEVER if we take a look at that wonderful closing `<li>` we see well theres no /... So once again thank you everyone, have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

If you just check it for being empty, it might not validate for white space. Trim the string before you check it for being empty as " " and "" are not equal

Try:

```
if(station.name.strip()!="")
```